# Как сделать проброс(?) в sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016

В нашей компании установлен Sharepoint 2016 Standard. Пользователи из внутренней сети могут к нему обращаться как по http://sharepoint/ так и по https://sharepoint.company.ru/

Можно ли настроить sharepoint (или что-то ещё) таким образом, чтобы пользователь обращаясь из своего браузера по http://sharepoint/.. попадал на https://sharepoint.company.ru/..?

Спасибо.

---

**English translation** (using Google Translate):

**Question title**: How to forward/redirect in SharePoint?

**Question**:

Our company has SharePoint 2016 Standard installed. Users from the internal network can access it both via `http://sharepoint/` and `https://sharepoint.company.ru/`.

Is it possible to configure SharePoint (or something else) so that when the user accesses from his browser via `http://sharepoint/..` will be redirected to `https://sharepoint.company.ru/..`?

Thank you.

Comment: Please take a look at: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/209001/redirect-http-to-https
And: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/64484/http-to-https-redirection-using-aam
Use google translate to get the Russian translation as I cant find Russian documentation online.

Comment: Thanks for reply, Martin. Previously, I already tried the solution with AAM. The problem is that it only works for root links. For example, the URL: "http://sps/Lists/" will not be converted to "https://sps.company.ru/Lists/". Only in "http://sps.company.ru/Lists/" and this is incorrect. The URL Rewrite Module solution doesn't work either. The installation  reaches 100 percent, then the changes are rolled back. On top of everything else, the IIS configuration file gets corrupted and most of the pools become unusable. I'm using IIS 10 and URL Rewrite Module 2.1